# Passing array in function

Tags: vbscript

I have an array that is read like this:

```
MyArray(0)='test'
MyArray(1)='test2'
MyArray(2)='test3'
```

How do I pass this through a function?

```
Function(MyArray(all_arrays))
```

What do I put for `all_arrays`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
MyArray(0)='test'
MyArray(1)='test2
MyArray(2)='test3'

AcceptArray MyArray

Private Function AcceptArray(myArray())
'Code here
End Function
```

You look to want to pass a string before the array.

So, change the Function to :

```
Private Function AcceptArray(param1, myArray)
'Code here
'Don't forget to return value of string type.
End Function
```

And you call this function like this:

```
returnValue = AcceptArray("MyString", MyArray)
```

If you do not need to return a value you should use a Sub.

Comment: When i pass function ('test', MyArray() as String) i get an error

Comment: You use it with : AcceptArray MyArray. If you want to pass other parameter you need to add it. I'll update my answer.

Comment: sorry, i dont understand, it wont let me put As String there.. it causes an error.

Comment: The reference I found online has: Private Function AcceptArray(byval param1, byref myArray)  try something like this out

Comment: I modified the snippet of code because I though you were coding in vb6 no in vbscript. You do not have to put the type of the variable with AS statement.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to define you function as such:

```
Function <FunctionName>(byref <list Name>)
```

then when you call it in your code use

```
<FunctionName>(MyArray)
```

found here:
http://www.herongyang.com/VBScript/Function-Procedure-Pass-Array-as-Argument.html

passing by referrence using just the array name allows you to pass in the entire array to the function

Comment: Im much more familiar with VB.net but the source I found looks simmilar enough.  hope this helps

Comment: what if the function has other values?
function( 'test' , MyArray() ) ?

Comment: just change the function definition accordingly. then call it in your code the same way.   define it as <FunctionName>(byval str, bref alist)  and then when you call it use <FunctionName>('test', MyArray)

Answer (score 1):

A simple example...

```
Dim MyArray(2)
MyArray(0) = "Test"
MyArray(1) = "Test2"
MyArray(2) = "Test3"

ProcessArray MyArray

' -------------------------------------
' ProcessArray
' -------------------------------------
Sub ProcessArray(ArrayToProcess())
  For i = 0 To 2
    WScript.Echo ArrayToProcess(i)
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Function parameters can not contain parenthesis. Arrays are passed as normal variables without `()`.

Comment: @AutomatedChaos Thanks for the downvote...but you're wrong. Did you actually try the code? I slightly modified it to make it easier for you to test (`DIM`med the array and added a loop to print the values).

Comment: Furthermore, the accepted answer is virtually identical to mine, but you didn't downvote it?

Comment: I didn't test you code. Now I did and it is actually working code so I corrected the downvote. *But* you shouldn't use parenthesis inside function parameters; they are not necessary and it is confusing. In VBScript you can practically use parenthesis everywhere, but that doesn't mean you should. And you are right about the accepted answer, I should have threated it the same (I am not on a personal crusade, just wanted to do some quality stuff here).

Comment: @AutomatedChaos I appreciate you changing your vote and I'm sorry I seemed so defensive. You are correct that the `()` are not required, but I can find nothing that indicates you should not use them in this manner. The only reference to it that I could find is on the [Sub Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt223ahx%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) reference page. Even that page isn't clear. I could interpret it as use `()` when the argument is an array or the `()` is optional. I kind of like using them because it is a reminder that you're passing an array.